# Using GetSaveFileName. I specify OFN_EXPLORER flag, but always get old dialog appearance unless I avoid using both hook and template

Tags: windows, winapi

Using GetSaveFileName. I specify the OFN_EXPLORER flag, but I always get old dialog appearance unless I avoid using both hook and template.  (lpfnHook and lpfnTemplate (and their respective "enable" flags) in OPENFILENAME structure)

If I avoid using just one or the other, I still get the old dialog appearance.   I also tried no template, but use the hook... but always return TRUE from it (I saw mention of "always returning false" from the hook as a way to GET the old interface).  It didn't seem to have any effect, though.

EDIT: Added relevant code:

```
ofn.lStructSize=sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
ofn.hInstance=RhInst;
ofn.hwndOwner=MainWh;
ofn.lpstrFilter=s;
ofn.lpstrCustomFilter=null;
ofn.nMaxCustFilter=0;
ofn.nFilterIndex=sel;

ofn.lpstrFile=fname;
ofn.nMaxFile=lstrl;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle=tfile;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle=lstrl;

if (path && lstrlen(path)) ofn.lpstrInitialDir=path;
else ofn.lpstrInitialDir=drive;

lstrcpy(SE_DefExt,ext);
ofn.lpstrDefExt=SE_DefExt;
if (titleid) ofn.lpstrTitle=title;
else ofn.lpstrTitle=null;

ofn.lpfnHook=(CommHookProc)MakeProcInstance((FARPROC)SEOpen32Hook,hInst);
ofn.lpTemplateName=NULL;
ofn.Flags=OFN_SHOWHELP | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | OFN_ENABLEHOOK  | OFN_EXPLORER
            | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;

if(allowfit)
    {
    ofn.lpTemplateName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(SAVETOFIT);
    ofn.Flags |= OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE;
    }

if (GetSaveFileName(&ofn))
    {
    // <snip>
    }
```

Note that "allowfit" is non-zero/true in this case.  If I comment out the setting of the flag for both OFN_ENABLEHOOK and OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE, I get the "new" dialog appearance.

**EDIT 2:
It looks now like I was confused on what I was seeing.  I believe in both cases, I'm getting the "new" OFN_EXPLORER behavior and appearance.  When I remove the OFN_EXPLORER flag, I get a very old style dialog box.

What I am trying to get to is the style of Save File dialog that has the Back and Forward button in the upper right, and (most importantly) an address box that I can type in.  All my previous comments and code descriptions (above) still apply; when I remove the Template and the Hook, I get my "back & forward" buttons, and my typeable address box (plus left-side browse tree)... when I leave the template and the hook in place -- I do not (instead has "Save in" picklist at top, and "standard places" along the left ("Recent places", "Desktop", ...).

Answer (score 1):

did you define `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500`?
Setting lStructSize to the win2000 size might help the dialog decide (If you need to support < NT5 you would have to do some version checking and use `OPENFILENAME_SIZE_VERSION_400` as the size on down-level systems)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to show some code? According to MSDN:

> You can provide an OFNHookProc hook
>   procedure for an Explorer-style Save
>   dialog box. To enable the hook
>   procedure, set the OFN_EXPLORER and
>   OFN_ENABLEHOOK flags in the Flags
>   member of the OPENFILENAME structure
>   and specify the address of the hook
>   procedure in the lpfnHook member.

So it seems like unless you are doing something weird, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As for the template, You should define DS_SHELLFONT.
http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/04/366987.aspx

Comment: See my "Edit 2" above.  It looks like I'm not fighting "old look/new look" as set by OFN_EXPLORER, I'm fighting some browser/non-browser behavior and appearance.  Any idea what I might need to do?  Sadly, I can't just remove my template and hook; those must stay.

Answer (score 0):

If you use both `OFN_EXPLORER` and `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` in Windows Vista and 7, you will get the  dialog boxes with XP style. If you remove `OFN_EXPLORER` you will get the older Win2k style. If you use `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` (or `OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE`) then the system will not use Vista/7 style.

Since Vista if you want to customize such dialogs you are advised to use the COM interfaces `IFileDialog`, `IFileOpenDialog`, and `IFileSaveDialog`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx.